# Array field post Node js but after show only first value

Tags: node.js

I am using post array field name but show only first please help.

```
<input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand">ADD more
<input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand">
```

Use this but post this data only get first value.

Comment: Did you try `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`?

Answer (score 1):

Both the input tags in your html have same `name` attribute. As far as HTML is concerned, it simply ignores the fields in a form with duplicate names.

If you want your inputs to be parsed as array by nodehs body parser, you will need to include the indices in the input tag name.

```
<input type="text" name="brand[0]" id="brand0">ADD more
<input type="text" name="brand[1]" id="brand1">
```

EDIT::

All the ids on a page are also expected to be unique.

Comment: [ 'gussi' ]
{ cate: 'Spo
  brand: [ '
  status: 'A
  submit: 'S
[ 'gussi' ]